# How do you prove $\|A-B\|_F^2 \geq \|\Sigma_A - \Sigma_B\|_F^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

Given the following matrices $A,B\in \Bbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with $A=U \Sigma_A V^t$ and $B=Q \Sigma_B R^t$ (full SVD), how do you prove

$$\|A-B\|_F^2 \geq \|\Sigma_A - \Sigma_B\|_F^2$$

Comment: Could you provide some more context?  What have you tried here?  How did the problem come up?

Comment: I suspect that we can come up with a proof using Weyl's inequalities, namely
$$
\sigma_{i+j-1}(X+Y)\leq\sigma_i(X)+\sigma_j(Y) \quad\text{for $1\leq i,j\leq n, \; i+j-1\leq n$}
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
\sigma_{i+j-1}(A)\leq\sigma_i(A-B)+\sigma_j(B) \quad\text{for $1\leq i,j\leq n, \; i+j-1\leq n$} \implies\\
\sigma_{i+j-1}(A) - \sigma_j(B) \leq \sigma_i(A-B) \quad\text{for $1\leq i,j\leq n, \; i+j-1\leq n$}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Not quite a proof, but here's a citation that will work.  The following is from the 1997 edition of Bhatia's Matrix analysis.

> **Problem III.6.13:** Let $A,B$ be any $n \times n$ matrices and let $\Phi$ be any symmetric gauge function on $\Bbb R^n$. Then
>   $$
> \Phi(s(A) - s(B)) \leq \Phi(s(A - B))
> $$

Now, taking $\Phi(x_1,\dots,x_n) := \sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}$ gives us the desired result.  In particular: $\Phi(s(A) - s(B)) = \|\Sigma_A - \Sigma_B\|_F$, and $\Phi(s(A-B)) = \|A-B\|_F$.